# How to shift frequency of whole audio file?

Tags: audio, sound, frequency

How can I shift the frequency of a whole audio file. So as if there was a sound at 500 Hz and I wanted to shift the audio by 50 Hz, that sound would then be at 550 Hz, and a sound at 1000 Hz would be shifted to 1050 Hz?

Comment: That wouldn't produce the desired result, I don't think. to transpose sounds equally - i.e. remain 'in key' with each other relatively, you need to multiply frequencies, not add. Freeware Audacity can probably do something like that, though it would likely be note-based rather than frequency.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by shifting the frequency spectrum? At the moment it's a bit unclear how we can help.. Tetsujin is right btw.

Comment: @Tetsujin how do you know what is the desired result? Frequency shifting is indeed a pretty exotic thing and is completely different from _pitch shift_, but sometimes it can actually give quite a useful effect.

Comment: spectralayers can scale/shift frequency...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That operation is indeed called *frequency shifting*. It can be achieved with a [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform). How is described in [this article](http://www56.homepage.villanova.edu/scott.sawyer/fpga/II_frequency_shifting.htm) – pretty easy to code it up yourself in any DSP language of choice<sup>1</sup>, but I'm not aware of any tools that offer this as a standard operation.

The thing is, frequency shifting is a pretty weird operation. For audio purposes, it is quite reminiscent of the typical ring-modulation character (which isn't entirely surprising, since it *is* implemented with multipliers). At any rate, if you frequency-shift, say, human voice, up a few Hz, it'll sound nothing like the same voice speaking/singing a tone higher, because the harmonics don't match anymore. Are you sure what you want is not [pitch shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_shift) (which *multiplies* all frequency by some factor)? That's available in many free or commercial implementations, e.g. [Rubber Band](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Much easier than pitch shift.</sub>

Comment: Ableton Live has a frequency shifter as part of its native audio effects.